# Data Transformation to convert one row into multiple rows

Tags: mysql

I do have a table which has the data as shown below.

```
Table_A

Row Id    Date1        Date2        Date3
1         1/12/2008    2/12/2008    3/12/2008
2         2/12/2010    NULL          NULL
3         3/12/2008    4/12/2008     NULL
```

I need to write a MySQL query to get result like this

```
Row Id    App_Date     Date1          Date2         Date3
1         1/12/2008    1/12/2008      2/12/2008     3/12/2008
1         2/12/2008    1/12/2008      2/12/2008     3/12/2008
1         3/12/2008    1/12/2008      2/12/2008     3/12/2008
2         2/12/2010    2/12/2010      NULL          NULL
3         3/12/2008    3/12/2008      4/12/2008     NULL
3         4/12/2008    3/12/2008      4/12/2008     NULL
```

Basically I want to populate a new column `App_Date` based on `Date1`, `Date2` and `Date3`. If any of the Date fields has any value.

Then I should create a record with the date populated in that column. For instance, if all the 3 dates populated on a record, I should have 3 records for that one record with the date populated in the new column `App_Date` like above.

What is the most optimal MySQL query to achieve this?

Comment: How many rows should be generated for a source row that has Date1 = Date2, and Date3 NULL?

Comment: It doesnt matter if they are equal. I need to have new row when I have some value in the Date column

Answer (score 0):

Supposing your number of date columns will always be 3, then you could write a `union` query like this:

```
select id, date1 as app_date, date1, date2, date3 from test
    where not isnull(date1)
union
select id, date2 as app_date, date1, date2, date3 from test
    where not isnull(date2)
union
select id, date3 as app_date, date1, date2, date3 from test
    where not isnull(date3)
order by id, app_date
```

Comment: UNION ALL may be more appropriate; UNION (DISTINCT implied) would eliminate "duplicates" when a row's date1 = date2, date1 = date3, or date2 = date3.